# Virtualenv problem

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have created a new environement in virtualenv with --no-site-packages and executed activate file. So, shouldn't my current Django app show any error? Environement doesn't have Django installed. I think, my site is using my old python with Django. How can I change it?
Maybe it's because my .htaccess file, here it is:

```
SetHandler mod_python
PythonPath  "['/home/usr/PythonEnvs/Django/bin/python', 'home/usr/apps'] + sys.path" 
PythonOption mod_python.importer.path "['/home/usr/PythonEnvs/Django/bin/python']+ sys.path" 
PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
PythonDebug On 

SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE application.settings 

SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /tmp/egg-cache
```

What else should I do to use my environement?

Answer (score 4):

With mod_wsgi, you can set `WSGIPythonHome` to where your virtualenv is. mod_python doesn't let you set the interpreter easily, however (there may be a way involving setting PYTHONEXECUTABLE at apache startup).

See what `bin/python` (next to `bin/activate`) does to `sys.path`, and mimick it in the `PythonPath` directive. Write a page that displays the current sys.path and make sure the system python path doesn't appear; if it does, edit it further with `PythonPath`.

Comment: +1. The OP (and everyone else) should be using mod_wsgi anyway.